# Substituting a hard coded label on Volusion (for translations)

Tags: html, css, volusion

I'm working on a project built on Volusion, but unfortunately this platform does not offer full interface edition capabilities so I am trying to edit some labels which are hardcoded into the HTML (I need them to show in spanish).

I tried multiple options discussed in this forum, but so far I am only able to add an alternative text "after" the labels through the CSS; take for example main title on Shopping Cart page (http://pkheu.ahnfg.servertrust.com/ShoppingCart.asp):

```
/* ========== ORIGINAL LABEL IS "YOUR CART" ============ */
.shoppingcart h2.v65-your-cart-title span {
  visibility: hidden;
  display: none;
} /*THIS DOESN'T DO ANYTHING AND WITHOUT THE SPAN IT DELETES THE DIV COMPLETELY*/

.shoppingcart h2.v65-your-cart-title:after {
  content: " / Su Orden"; 
  margin: 15px 0 0;
  visibility: visible;
} /*THIS AT LEAST PERMITS ME TO ADD "/ SU ORDEN" AS A SPANISH ALTERNATIVE*/
```

Would appreciate any advise on effective way to fully substitute the content on the div on Volusion HTML interface (ie delete the original "Your Cart" from view). Thanks in advance.

Cheers! Max

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to accomplish what you want without using JavaScript would be to add the following to your template.css file.

```
h2.v65-your-cart-title { display:none; }
```

Then simply add the following HTML to the bottom of your article 64 code.

```
<h2 class="v65-your-cart-title-spanish">Su Orden</h2>
```

Comment: Hi user357034! Thanks so much for the tip, it did work!!! I do have some additional coding matters to hire someone to do on our store. If you are interested can you please contact me directly max atsign noospheracr dot com. Thank you!